# Скрипт автоматической записи трансляций

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

появилась задача записывать трансляции twitch для дальнейшего монтажа.

Написал скрипт на Python с помощью livestreamer и кодека ffmpeg для записи.

На стадии монтажа возникла проблема. Оказалось что все записи идут с переменной частотой кадров.

В Sony Vegas и Adobe Premiere идет рассинхрон звука и видео.
Хоть в последней версии Adobe Premiere добавили поддержку работы с переменной частотой кадров, но она у меня не справлялась (также шел рассинхрон).

Нашел способы монтажа такого видео:

1. Перед монтажом сохранить видео в постоянную частоту кадров (по сути произвести лишний дополнительный рендеринг записи) - не вариант
2. Открыть видео в Sony Vegas, вытащить аудио дорожку, и подставлять ее по видео в монтаже - не вариант.

Чтобы избавиться от этого необходимо просто сразу записывать с постоянной частотой кадров. Но как это реализовать в автоматическом режиме.

Решил использовать Bandicam с постоянной частотой кадров.

С помощью API Twitch в бесконечной цикле проверяем наличие трансляции на канале.

В случае начала трансляции, открываем браузер с помощью Selenium в полноэкраном режиме, запускаем Bandicam с помощью командной строки (subprocess) и начинаем запись.

В случае, если стрим заканчивается, останавливаем запись и закрываем браузер.

Как думаете, я заморочился, или есть более лучшие способы организовать запись с постоянной частотой?

И как включить полноэкранный режим (также как и в браузере - F11, или у каждого браузера есть специальная настройка такая)?

**Update**

```
cls && @echo off & setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion 
set "_tag_00=%*"
set "_tag_01=--ignore-errors --abort-on-error --ignore-config --flat-playlist --geo-bypass "
set "_tag_02=--restrict-filenames --no-part --no-cache-dir --write-thumbnail --prefer-ffmpeg "
set "_tag_03=--ffmpeg-location .\ --postprocessor-args  -i "%%(title)s.%%(ext)s" -vf fps^=fps^=60^,"
set "_tag_04=scale^=1920x1080 -c:v libx264 -b:v 500k -preset superfast -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time "
set "_tag_05=60 %%^(title^)s.mp4"

youtube-dl "https://www.twitch.tv/gamesprouttv" -f "bestvideo[ext=mp4]+bestaudio[ext=m4a]/best[ext=mp4]/best" -o "%%^(title^)s.%%^(ext^)s" !_tag_1!!_tag_2!!_tag_3!!_tag_4!!_tag_5!
```

Comment: Взять youtube-dl и не мучаться? (Нет, несмотря на название, оно поддерживает Twitch)

Comment: @andreymal он может записывать видео в онлайн режиме (пока идет трасляция)?

Comment: Не пробовал, но буквально пару часов назад с его помощью записывал трансляцию из ВКонтакте — наверняка и Twitch может. А ещё он написан на Python, возможно это тоже многое упростит (правда, требует наличие команды ffmpeg для своей работы)

Comment: @аndreaymal а частота кадров какая? постоянная? просто я где-то читал, что трансляции идут с переменной частотой кадров

Comment: Для youtube-dl нет понятия частоты кадров, он просто скачивает существующий поток как есть без каких-либо декодирований и преобразований (кроме складывания в предпочтаемый вами медиаконтейнер)

Comment: @andreymal так в том то и проблема что поток идет с переменной частотой кадров

Comment: Это не имеет никакого значения, потому youtube-dl просто сохраняет оригинальный поток как есть без изменений. Вы попробуйте скачать поток с помощью youtube-dl, а потом уже посмотрите, что получится

Comment: Если вам очень хочется избавиться от переменной частоты кадров и получить постоянную, то перекодирование/рендеринг — единственный возможный вариант. По сути с bandicam'ом вы тоже выполняете перекодирование на лету, только извращённым способом

Comment: @andreamal, ну допустим трансляция идет 5 часа. Это допустим весит 20 Гбайт. По окончании трансляции мне нужно потратить время на рендеринг дополнительный. А так у меня уже будет видео с которым можно работать

Comment: Для примера, вот такая длинная bash-команда `ffmpeg -i \`youtube-dl --get-url https://www.twitch.tv/stylesx2\` -vf fps=fps=10,scale=426x240 -c:v libx264 -b:v 500k -preset superfast -c:a copy -f segment -segment_time 60 stream-%04d.mp4` получает ссылку на поток с помощью youtube-dl и потом с помощью ffmpeg транскодирует его на лету в постоянные 10 кадров в секунду с уменьшением размера, а также попутно делит видео на отдельные файлы по минуте (если делить не надо, то, разумеется, соответствующие аргументы можно стереть)

Comment: Однако я не проверял многочасовую стабильность и не проверял проблем с рассинхроном (у меня вообще никогда не было проблем с синхронизацией). Тем не менее я вам дал пищу для размышлений какую могу и предлагаю дальше поэкспериментировать с youtube-dl и ffmpeg самостоятельно

Comment: @andreamal а не сможете переписать bash-скрипт под CMD?

Comment: Неа, в cmd я плохо разбираюсь

Comment: @andreymal можете хотябы расписать, что делают ваши скорашения? Половину разобрал, половину не пойму

Comment: @andreymal что такое -vf

Comment: Видеофильтры, читайте документацию ffmpeg

Comment: @andreymal c горем пополам мне помогла написать похожий скрипт на cmd, но он почему не делит видео на части, код добавил выше. У вас он точно делит? Если можно то скриншот покажите